# Apple Script for system preferences

Tags: applescript

In our college we all share the iMacs with same user account, say- Anonymous. So when some other user comes and uses my system, he/she generally changes some of the properties in system preferences.
It always wastes some of my precious time when I restore its setting according to mine.

So, I am thinking -

> can I make an apple script which when
>   executed sets setting in system
>   preferences according to my choices?

Thanks in advance for any help, suggestion or useful link!

Miraaj

Comment: macosxautomation.com has a nice article about changing systempreferences using applescript at [http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html)

Comment: @NikolausGradwohl : can you make this comment as answer?

Comment: @Aravindhanarvi it was an answer and has been converted to a comment by someone

Answer (score 0):

[Mac OS X Automation has an entire section with example scripts.](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html) Depending on the preferences you wish to alter, you will have to go through the System Preferences application or the System Events addition. Some you might still have to use GUI scripting to set.